# VmWare : listening nat in promiscuous mode

Tags: networking, nat

[This](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_nat.html) document describe how NAT in VmWare works.

Next picture is from that document.

[image: Nat]

Is there way to configure Virtual Ethernet switch in that way:
All packets arrived from nat send to specified Virtual Ethernet Adapner regardless of it's destination IP?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the he

Comment: Vote to keep open - one set of people most capable of answering such a question are software developers who work with these types of configurations.